# Map works slow after loading some pushpins in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am facing a problem that after loading some pushpins map works very slow and even sometimes it is not moving. And it makes very hard to use our application.

Kindly help me out or guide me what to do.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Show us some code? How do you add pushpins?

Answer (score 1):

If the BitmapCache is not enough you can also implement pushpin clustering or limit the max pushpins on the screen.

[Pushpin clastering](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/pushpin-clustering-with-the-windows-phone-7-bing-map-control/)

Comment: Hi Andras, we have applied pushpin clustering in it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the CacheMode of your Map to BitmapCache, this should improve performance, as detailed in the following blog post :-

http://mindre.net/Article/windows_phone_7__cachemode_and_why_it_matters

Answer (score 0):

The guys that developed WP7Contrib (on CodePlex) wrote a blogpost on pushpin performance with WP7.

http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/how-many-pins-can-bing-maps-handle-in.html

Might give you some pointers?